# How to write a dynamically generated pdf string to a file in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

I am interacting with a webservice. That webservice returns a string which I should write to a pdf file. I have to work with ruby 1.8.7. I have been unable so far to generate a valid pdf string and write to a file. How can I write the string obtained from the api to a file in pdf format successfully. I have tried variations of the following:

```
File.open("public/data/input.pdf", "wb") do |f|
  f.write string
  # also tried: f.write Base64.decode64 string
end
```

But so far both the options are not working. How can I convert the data into a valid pdf file?

Answer (score -1):

you still need to generate headers so that filesystem know that they're dealing with a pdf file.  you can look at [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) or [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) or [prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) to do this.